How to bulk delete container images in GCP?
When I use GCP AppEngine, it creates a lot of container images. To delete one image, I have to drill down the actual image and select all the tags.
I tried gcloud container images list, but it also won't list all the images and their tags.
Is there a way to delete all the images and their tags in one go?
